# ipinfo.io via PHP's file_get_contents() and cURL fail

Tags: php, curl

I try to get a GeoLocation data from http://ipinfo.io,

Here is my way :

```
$resp = file_get_contents('http://ipinfo.io/json');
$data = json_decode($resp);
```

It return an error :

```
Warning: file_get_contents(http://ipinfo.io/json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in ....
```

But then I access the link (http://ipinfo.io/json) manually in the URL box of my browser, it shows a correct json.

I also try it with cURL :

```
$curlSession = curl_init();

curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_URL, "ipinfo.io/json");
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($curlSession, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);

$resp = curl_exec($curlSession);

if (FALSE === $resp) {
  echo curl_errno($curlSession);
} 

curl_close($curlSession);
```

It echo a number of 7, and i look up in the internet, error 7 means Couldn't connect to the server.

Any idea why ?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I run http://ipinfo.io, and we don't block access to any IPs (we do rate limit requests from IPs, but that'd result in a HTTP status code, not a blocked connection). This sounds like a config issue with your server to me. Some hosts lock down `file_get_contents` so it can't open URLs, or might have blocked http://ipinfo.io. Are few ways to track this down:

1) Can you open another URL with `file_get_contents`? Eg. what happens when you `file_get_contents('http://google.com')`. If you get a permission denied error there then you should speak to your hosting provider

2) Does command line `curl` work for ipinfo.io? The `-i -v` flags should give you more information about what's going on here. Here's what a successful request looks like:

```
$ curl -iv ipinfo.io
* Rebuilt URL to: ipinfo.io/
*   Trying 54.68.119.255...
* Connected to ipinfo.io (54.68.119.255) port 80 (#0)
> GET / HTTP/1.1
> Host: ipinfo.io
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Date: Sun, 15 Jan 2017 18:38:44 GMT
Date: Sun, 15 Jan 2017 18:38:44 GMT
< Server: nginx/1.8.1
Server: nginx/1.8.1
< Set-Cookie: first_referrer=; Path=/
Set-Cookie: first_referrer=; Path=/
< X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
< Content-Length: 252
Content-Length: 252
< Connection: keep-alive
Connection: keep-alive

<
{
  "ip": "24.6.61.239",
  "hostname": "c-24-6-61-239.hsd1.ca.comcast.net",
  "city": "Mountain View",
  "region": "California",
  "country": "US",
  "loc": "37.3845,-122.0881",
  "org": "AS7922 Comcast Cable Communications, LLC",
  "postal": "94040"
* Connection #0 to host ipinfo.io left intact
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Quite often a server will be configured to prevent requests where there is no `User-Agent` string present in the request headers so you can add a `context` argument to `file_get_contents` that supplies a User-Agent and any other headers you need.

```
$args=array(
    'http'=>array(
        'method' => "GET",
        'header' => implode( "\n", array(
                    'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; rv:44.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/44.0',
                    'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8',
                    'Host: ipinfo.io'
                )
            )
        )
    );
/* create the context */
$context=stream_context_create( $args );

$resp = file_get_contents( 'http://ipinfo.io/json', FILE_TEXT, $context );
$data = json_decode( $resp );
echo '<pre>',print_r( $data,true ),'</pre>';
```

Comment: yeah that's quite normal, but ipinfo.io doesn't care about the UA string, so that aint the problem here

Comment: I'll have to take your word for that - I used the above and it produced a valid JSON response with my IP details all nicely printed...

Comment: no need to take my word for it, just send a request without an user-agent and see for yourself: ```<?php $sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
socket_connect($sock,gethostbyname('ipinfo.io'),80);
socket_write($sock,"GET /json HTTP/1.0\r\nHost: ipinfo.io\r\n\r\n");
$response=socket_read($sock,999,PHP_BINARY_READ);
socket_close($sock);
var_dump($response);?>```

Comment: when the ONLY http headers are `GET /json HTTP/1.0` and `Host: ipinfo.io`, i get ```string(486) "HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *
Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
Date: Sat, 14 Jan 2017 14:39:12 GMT
Server: nginx/1.8.1
Set-Cookie: first_referrer=; Path=/
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Length: 220
Connection: Close

{
  "ip": "85.164.188.10",
  "hostname": "ti0016a400-3325.bb.online.no",
  "city": "Andebu",
  "region": "Vestfold",
  "country": "NO",
  "loc": "59.3059,10.1765",
  "org": "AS2119 Telenor Norge AS",
  "postal": "3158"
}"
```

Comment: I don't know why, i copy your code and did not make any changes (Only adding die after the echo with print_r), it did not work. Permission Denied is still shown. But thanks for the idea, appreciate it so much.

Comment: I tried your way with another IP-Geolocation link, it also returned permission denied, am i doing it wrong or i have a bad IP DNS ?,

Answer (score 0):

i see 2 plausible explanations here.

1: you use a shitty DNS server. try GoogleDNS (8.8.8.8) instead. 
curl_setopt($curlSession,CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4,'8.8.8.8');

if that fixes it, contact your DNS provider and sort it out with them

2: you're IP banned. try to just create a TCP socket to their ip, see if you can do that.

```
<?php
$sock=socket_create(AF_INET,SOCK_STREAM,SOL_TCP);
var_dump($sock,socket_connect($sock,gethostbyname('ipinfo.io'),80),socket_close($sock));
```

if you can't do that, you're probably IP banned

Comment: I use PHP 5.4 so CURLOPT_DNS_LOCAL_IP4 is undefined (I read it only for PHP 7 above). I also tried your second explanation, and here i got : `Warning: socket_connect(): unable to connect [13]: Permission denied in ...
resource(65) of type (Unknown) bool(false) NULL `, Do you think my IP is banned ?, Thank you very much for the answer by the way.

Comment: @MarcelAngir i didn't expect that error from socket_connect... a quick google search suggest that SELinux is messing the connect() syscall. are you using SELinux?